# Scala cats. How do I write Kleisli[F[_],A,B].ap?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

I tried to write a *Kleisli.ap* function.

```
final case class Kleisli[F[_], -A, B](run: (A) ⇒ F[B]) extends Product with Serializable

def ap[C, D, AA <: A](f: Kleisli[F, AA, C])(implicit F: Apply[F], ev: As[B, (C) ⇒ D]): Kleisli[F, AA, D]
```

but

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._
import cats.data._

val x: Kleisli[Option,String,Int] = Kleisli(_ => Some(1))
val y: Kleisli[Option,String,Double] = Kleisli(_ => Some(1.0))

val kleisliAp: Kleisli[Option,String,Double] = x.ap(y)
// No implicits found for parameter ev: As[Int, Double => D_]
```

I saw this error code and looked for a way to create an instance of *As[A,B]* but could not find one.
Please let me know if you know how to solve this problem.

Comment: `cats` ap function has following signature: `def ap[C, AA <: A](f: Kleisli[F, AA, B => C])(implicit F: Apply[F]): Kleisli[F, AA, C]`. This can be used as `x.ap(y)` if definition of y is something like: `val y: Kleisli[Option,String, Int => Double] = Kleisli(_ => Option(_.toDouble))`.

Answer (score 0):

`ap` is the wrong way to combine the two objects you have.

`ap` requires an `F[A]` and an `F[A => B]`. You have an `F[A]` and an `F[B]`

Instead, use `mapN`

`(x, y).mapN { (int, double) => ??? }`

---

Additionally, `ap` is considered bad style in scala FP. The shape of it is really not suited to scala; it's there because it's part of the foundation of `Apply` but `mapN` is the idiomatic way to compose objects applicatively